# WordPress сайт на локальном сервере медленно работает

Tags: wordpress, gulp, openserver

WordPress установлен на OpenServer, сборка проекта идет через Gulp. Вся эта связка работает очень медленно, при внесении каких либо изменений обновление (через browser-sync) происходит где-то в течении 35-45 сек. Без WP работает нормально. Как нормализовать скорость загрузки?

Comment: Выкинуть всю эту хрень и использовать родное окружение. См [раз](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-themes/#post-304429), или [два](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc/#post-278407)

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было подключить все скрипты и стили в файле functions.php, через wp_enqueue_scripts. скорость запуска сократилась до 1-2 сек